# Probability of arriving H before A

Tags: probability, recursive-algorithms, binomial-distribution

I m  in the point X. I m 2 blocks up from a point A and 3 blocks down from my home H. Every time I walk one block i drop a coin.

H
.
.
.
X
.
.
A

If  the coin is face I go one block up and if it is not face I go one block down.

Which is the probability of arriving home before the point A?

---

What I really want to do is to solve that problem in a recursive way. Maybe it can be solved with a binomial distribution... But is it also recursive?

Comment: How often are you dropping the coin and what unit of distance do you move in either direction after the coin is dropped? It sounds like you may have visited the pub before writing this question! :)

Comment: Ahhh OK Alex... I get the point... But what I really want to do is to solve that problem in a recursive way. Maybe is a binomical distribution an it can be solve... But is it also recursive?

Comment: @paulofer85 I think you'd want touse a Markov chain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: reformulate your problem to say: If I start on the origin $(0,0)$ toss a coin,  I move left one unit to $(-1,0)$ if the coin is tails, if the coin lands heads, I move one unit to the right to $(1,0)$. After I move one unit, I toss the coin again and determine my direction of movement in the same way. What is the probability I reach $(3,0)$ before $(-2,0)$? Read this to help you in your problem solving efforts http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html. Of course, this doesn't factor in getting tired of tossing the coin, giving up, and going to the pub anyway out of frustration!

Comment: @Nathan... Yes you are right i m trying to solve it that way. I ll read that an see if i get the same result than solving it as a binomocal.

Comment: @Alex this is probability there is no need of having a system reference but if you need that to understand the point I 'll change it just for you. Nathan got the point...

Comment: @paulofer85, I was simply trying to minimize your down-votes by formulating it more clearly! Visit that web page and all you should need to do is some plug-and-play. Happy hunting!

Comment: @paulofer85 OK, so I toss heads, go two steps toward home, toss again, heads again, so I take eight steps toward home, toss again, tails, I walk one mile in the direction of the pub, only I never finish the mile because I reach the pub first. There, that meets all the requirements of the problem _as you originally stated it_, because you never said how often to flip the coin (that is, how far to walk before flipping again). You don't _have_ to use Alex's suggestion to patch up this ambiguity, but it is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forming a Stochastic Matrix, with the first row being the pub and the last row being home.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
We are solving:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(A^x\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix})$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\0.8&0&0&0&0&0.2\\0.6&0&0&0&0&0.4\\0.4&0&0&0&0&0.6\\0.2&0&0&0&0&0.8\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0&0&0&0&0.4\end{bmatrix}$$
The last column represents the probability we are at home, which is $0.4$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote your current position by $S_0=0$, and let the pub be $2$ and home $-3$. Define the probability
$$
P(\text{A before H} \mid S_n = x)=:p(x)
$$
This probability satisfies
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{2}p(x+1) + \frac{1}{2}p(x-1)
$$
As a difference eqution:
$$
p_{n+2}-2p_{n+1}+p_{n}=0
$$
which has a single root  $1$ so the solution is
$$
p_n = c_1 + c_2n
$$
now plug in the boundaries $p(-3)=0$ and $p(2)=1$ and evaluate at $n=0$ which yields 
$$
p(0) = \frac{3}{5}
$$
(edit: I solved for the opposite event of what you wanted)

Comment: Yes and finally here we have  `1-3/5= 2/5 = 0.4` the same result from Nathan 's answer.